# C print and store command line argument in a round robin manner

Tags: c

I am new to c programming and I have encountered this implementation problem. The situation is I need to use `fork()` to create 4 child process to print command line arguments in a round robin manner, that is if the input is `./abc.c RR GG EE WW BB CC DD AA`, child process 1 should store and print `RR BB`, child process 2 should store and print `GG CC` and so on. The final output should look like this.

```
Child 1, pid 23460: S5 HT DK S4 H7 S6 S8 D2 H3 H2 DT DA S9
Child 2, pid 23461: C7 HA D6 S7 SQ HK H6 H4 C3 CK S2 C9 SJ
```

3 and 4th child process has similar output.

The problem is the store part. How can we store these argument properly and use printf or other method to produce the above output?  One child process print one line. I cannot figure out the solution.

Store requirement is to store Child 1 element is an array. `S5 HT DK S4 H7 S6 S8 D2 H3 H2 DT DA S9`, store Child 2 elements in an array. `C7 HA D6 S7 SQ HK H6 H4 C3 CK S2 C9 SJ` and so on.

Here is what I have got at this moment.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

void childFunction( char *argv[], int identify ){
    int i;  
    for (i=1;i<sizeof(argv);i+=4){ 
      switch (identify){
        case 0:   
            printf("Child : %d %s\n", identify+1, argv[i]); 
            break;
        case 1:
            printf("Child : %d %s\n", identify+1, argv[i+1]); 
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Child : %d %s\n", identify+1, argv[i+2]); 
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Child : %d %s\n", identify+1, argv[i+3]); 
            break;
        }
    }
    // do stuff
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){
    int childLimit = 4; // number of children wanted
    int childrenPids[childLimit]; // array to store children's PIDs if needed
    int currentPid, i;

    for(i=0; i<childLimit; i++){
        switch(currentPid = fork()){
            case 0:
                // in the child
                childFunction(argv, i);
                // exit the child normally and prevent the child
                // from iterating again
                return 0;
            case -1:
                printf("Error when forking\n");
                break;
            default:
                // in the father
                childrenPids[i] = currentPid; // store current child pid
                break;
        }

    }

    printf("Father : %d childs created\n", i);

    // do stuff in the father

    //wait for all child created to die
    waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);
}
```

Updated requirement: 
I need to further clarify the requirement, that is I need to **print**, **maintain** *each* child process's member element in an **array** with a new *ascending* **sorting** requirement.

code *amended* according to the first answer:

```
 for( i = childnum; i < argc; i += 4 )
{  
    for( j = 0; j < argc; j++ )
    {
        a[j] = argv[i];  
        printf("%s ", a[j]) ; 
        break; 
    } 
}
```

it produce the following output:

```
    ./a.out ff ee gg tt hh oo ee pp
Child : 1, pid 762 : ff hh 
Child : 3, pid 764 : gg ee 
Child : 2, pid 763 : ee oo 
Father : 4 childs created
Child : 4, pid 765 : tt pp
```

The output look great, but how to store them in **separate** arrays and perform some **sorting**, i.e ascending order of Child 1 elements?

Comment: It would be far less confusing if your example output was both complete (i e. all four processes), and matched the earlier description of example input.

Comment: What do you mean by "store"? Store where, and for what purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `childFunction()` if your iteration starts from `identify + 1`, then the iteration index can be used directly to select the argument without the need for a switch, thus:

```
void childFunction( char *argv[], int argc, int identify )
{
    int childnum = identify + 1 ;

    printf("Child : %d, pid %d : ", childnum, getpid() ); 
    for( int i = childnum; i < argc; i += 4 )
    { 
        printf("%s ", argv[i] ) ; 
    }
    printf( "\n" ) ;
}
```

Note the need to pass `argc` to `chiledFunction()`; `sizeof(argv)` is not a count of the number of arguments - it is the size of a `char**` pointer; in your `main()` the call should be changed thus:

```
        childFunction(argv, argc, i);
```

Another advised change is to output the father text *after* the `waitpid()`:

```
    //wait for all child created to die
    waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);

    printf("Father : %d children created\n", i);
```

otherwise its output is likely to appear in the middle of that of the child processes.

The suggested changes result in the following (in my test):

```
sh-4.2$ main 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88                                                                                                                                                                                               
Child : 1, pid 156 : 11 55                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Child : 3, pid 158 : 33 77                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Child : 2, pid 157 : 22 66                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Child : 4, pid 159 : 44 88                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Father : 4 children created
```

Note the order of child execution is not deterministic.  In the above example the order is 1, 3, 2, 4, but in other tests is was 1, 2, 3, 4 - YMMV.

Comment: One more question.  If I want to store 11 55 in array, 33 77 in other array, 22 66 in the third array and 44 88 in fourth array. Then what should I do?

Comment: @SamAnnie :  If that is a clarification of your "store" requirement, then it should be clarified *in* the question rather then posted as a comment.  If it is a separate question (and it really should be in any case) then post a separate question.  Comments are neither for questions or answers.  However, the rather obvious solution is to maintain a second counter (say `j`)  that is incremented by 1 rather then 4 in the loop and then assign `child_argv[j] = argv[i] ;`.  If you were to update your question so it includes this requirement then I can legitimately add it to this answer.

Comment: the question has been updated according to your answer.  Please provide updated answer about this question.

Comment: @SamAnnie: As I suggested, your additional requirement is sufficiently extensive and unrelated to the first as to warrant a separate post.  Sorting can easily be performed using the standard library `qsort()` function - it hardly deserves modification of the answer.  If you are struggling with using `qsort()` then that definitely deserves a separate question.