# fork() with char array and qsort() resulting child stop working

Tags: c, arrays

I have encountered some problems on using `qsort()` function. The situation is an extension to my previously added post [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42325032/c-print-and-store-command-line-argument-in-a-round-robin-manner/42325301?noredirect=1#comment72082753_42325301). I need to sort the arrays that store the members received elements (i.e suit of cards). For example:

with the following sample run -

```
./a.out A4 B2 CK DA BJ A3 DT C4 A2 B3 D4 C3
Child : 1, pid 18211 : A4 BJ A2
Child : 2, pid 18212 : B2 A3 B3
Child : 3, pid 18213 : CK DT D4
Child : 4, pid 18214 : C4 DA C3
Father : 4 childs created
```

desired output

```
./a.out A4 B2 CK DA BJ A3 DT C4 A2 B3 D4 C3
    Child : 1, pid 18211 : A4 A2 BJ
    Child : 2, pid 18212 : A3 B3 B2
    Child : 3, pid 18213 : CK DT D4
    Child : 4, pid 18214 : C4 C3 DA
    Father : 4 childs created
```

that is save A4 BJ A2 in an array, save B2 A3 B3 in 2nd array, save CK DT D4 in 3rd array, save C4 DA C3 in 4th array. And sort the member elements in descending order and do further operations.

However, when I try to use qsort, i have the following problem:

there are no child output (even if the unsorted print statement)

What is the problem? is there any problem in the qsort implementation? 
Please help me.

Code have so far:

```
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <string.h>

    void childFunction( char *argv[], int argc, int identify ){
        int cmp( const void *a, const void *b ){
            return *(char *)a - *(char *)b; 
        }
        int childnum = identify + 1 ;
        int i,j,r,z; 
        char *a[256];
        char *temp[256];
        printf("Child : %d, pid %d : ", childnum, getpid() ); 
        for( i = childnum; i < argc; i += 4 )
        {  
            for( j = 0; j < argc; j++ )
            {
                a[j] = argv[i];  
                printf("%s ", a[j]) ; 
                break; 
            } 
        } 
        qsort(a,sizeof(a),sizeof(a[0]),cmp);
        printf( "\n" ) ;
         for( j = 0; j < sizeof(a); j++ )
            { 
                printf("%s ", a[j]) ; 
                break; 
            } 
        // do stuff
    }


    int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){
        int childLimit = 4; // number of children wanted
        int childrenPids[childLimit]; // array to store children's PIDs if needed
        int currentPid, i;

        for(i=0; i<childLimit; i++){
            switch(currentPid = fork()){
                case 0:
                    // in the child
                    childFunction(argv, argc, i);
                    // exit the child normally and prevent the child
                    // from iterating again
                    return 0;
                case -1:
                    printf("Error when forking\n");
                    break;
                default:
                    // in the father
                    childrenPids[i] = currentPid; // store current child pid
                    break;
            }

        }



        // do stuff in the father

        //wait for all child created to die
        waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);
        printf("Father : %d childs created\n", i);
    }


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42325032/c-print-and-store-command-line-argument-in-a-round-robin-manner/42325301?noredirect=1#comment72082753_42325301
```

Comment: Well to begin with your program is not really a valid C program, since C doesn't have nested functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a problem with how you're calling `qsort`.

The 2nd argument is meant to be the number of members in your array. `sizeof(a)` returns the entire size of `a` which in this case is 2048 bytes (256 elements * 8 bytes for a pointer). What you actually want here is to keep track of how many elements of a you're populating and use that value instead.

Which sort of leads on to the another issue, namely that the way you're populating `a` doesn't make much sense and I can't see how you got your output from it. You're filling the first `argc` elements of the array with `argv[i]` repeatedly for different values of `i`.

I'm thinking you meant something like:

```
for( i = childnum; i < argc; i += 4 )
   {
   a[j++]=a[i];
   }
```

Which then gives you `j` as the number of elements to pass into `qsort`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read a little more about [the `qsort` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort), and what it passes to the comparison function.

The `qsort` function will call the comparison function passing pointers to the element in the array. I.e. in your case it will call your function like e.g.

```
cmp(&a[0], &a[1]);
```

Since you have an array of pointers, the arguments to `cmp` are pointers *to pointers*, the arguments are really `char **`.

So you have an invalid cast and subtract the lowest byte of two pointers in your function.

If you want to compare the first character of each string, you need to use the correct casting and dereferencing in the function:

```
return **(char **)a - **(char **)b;
```